# Анимация слов перелистывания

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, текст

Есть задача так что бы слова МАРКЕТИНГОМ,ДІДЖИТАЛ,БРЕНДІНГОМ менялись анимацией перелистывания определенное время ,бордер оставался на месте.Сделал свою версию,но кривая до ужаса и на мобилку не пойдёт.

- [Дизайн] http://skrinshoter.ru/s/230320/JAIVpUIL
- [Пример анимации] https://skrinshoter.ru/v/190320/EVQowOk7

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&display=swap');

  font-family: Ubuntu; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 48px; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 0.03em; text-transform: uppercase; color: #000000;

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анимация текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097050/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: закройте прошлый вопрос, отметьте любой ответ решением

Comment: Sevastopol,так подумал нужно только зафиксировать "працюємо з' а слова пусть подстраиваются ,но положение должно быть такое http://skrinshoter.ru/s/240320/9deRiazI

Comment: При @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&display=swap');

*{
  font-weight:Bold;
  font-family:Ubuntu;
  text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:48px;  letter-spacing: 0.03em;

} всё плывёт не могу составить нормальные пропорции